# Home Refurbishment

Tags: electrical

Incoming electric supply 3 phase 69Kva 100amp.
Is this sufficient for 9 x 1bed flats with gas for heating and hot water.
What Kva is required for 9 x 1bed flats?

Comment: I presume from this being a 690V service that you are in an area that uses IEC-style power distribution?

Answer (score -1):

It depends on your location, but in most places, there are codes / laws that will determine the configuration and capacity required for a multi-tenant dwelling.

For example almost everywhere in the United States, you are bound by the National Electrical Code (NEC) - different revisions / amendments / additions may apply, but the NEC is the basis.

The NEC includes guidelines for **load calculations** that determine the minimum size of the service in these situations.  These calculations take into account the type of heating and cooling and hot water, high demand appliances, lighting, and general use given the size and type of building.  These calculations account for **non-concurrent loads** - for example, heating and air conditioning are not expected to run at the same time, so only the larger of the two is factored into the load calculation.  They also account for **diversity** - the fact that you won't usually turn on everything at once.

It's very unlikely that a 100 amp three phase service is going to cut it for nine units.  The service has to be able to handle peak demand, not average demand.

From a business perspective, in these situations there's usually a cost analysis performed to see whether you're better off all electric, or using gas where ever possible.  Gas usually results in lower utility bills, but electrical is usually cheaper to install and maintain.

A load calculation may be performed by a qualified electrician or an engineer.  An electrical contractor may be more helpful, because they can perform both the load calculations and the cost estimates.